# Scalaz - combining List and State Monad in for comprehension

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers, scalaz7

I am planning to start using Monadic style in my Scala code for, amongst others, threading state. Here's a simplified example of combining 3 monadic functions (and caring only about the side effects)

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object MonadTest {
  def adder(i: Int) = State[String, Int] ({str: String => (str + i.toString + " ", i) })
  val oneTwoThreeMonad = for {
    m1 <- adder(1)
    m2 <- adder(2)
    m3 <- adder(3)
  } yield m3
  oneTwoThreeMonad("start: ")._1 //String = "start: 1 2 3 "
}
```

This all is pretty self-explanatory and works as expected. But for this approach to be really useful to me I would like to be able to combine it with `List` for-comprehension. Here's a bit of (not working) code to show what I mean:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)

val oneTwoThreeBis = for {
  i <- list
  mx <- adder(i)
} yield mx
```

Basically I would like to be able to combine monads based on arguments from a `List` - run the monadic function on each of the elements of the `list` and accumulate the side-effects as I go. I understand the example syntax doesn't work and I see why it doesn't - I'm just looking for a clean, elegant equivalent.

I am pretty sure it is possible to achieve this using scalaz monad transformers, more specifically with `StateT` but I'm not really sure how one would go about doing it.

PS. I'm using Scalaz 7.0-M3, so the syntax might be a little different from the most common 6.x.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're looking for, but it sounds like you want something more like `traverse` here (where `traverse` is a more general version of Haskell's `mapM`):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def adder(i: Int) = State[String, Int](str => (str + i.toString + " ", i))

List(1, 2, 3).traverseS(adder)("start: ")._1
```

This will print the following, as expected:

```
res0: String = "start: 1 2 3 "
```

Note that I'm using `traverseS` (where the `S` stands for `State`) to avoid having to write out the rather messy type parameter, but `traverse` is more generally useful anytime you want to map a monadic function over something traversable.

I'm happy to give a `StateT` example if this isn't what you wanted, but that's going to end up with you having something of type `List[(String, Int)]`.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I'm looking for. But it doesn't change the fact I'm going to have to learn to use state transformers in practice sooner or later ;)

Comment: I just realized I already read one of your answers containing a detailed description of `traverse` and `traverseS` and even praised you for it. I can't imagine how it didn't stick with me...

Comment: If anyone needs to do something similar with Cats rather than Scalaz, note there is no `traverseS` but I have a working example of it using `traverseU` here: https://github.com/benhutchison/gesture/blob/master/core/jvm/src/test/scala/gesture/GestureProcessorSpec.scala#L34